# F# - How to test an exception raised in the constructor with fsunit?

Tags: f#, fsunit

I want to check if an argument passed to the *constructor* of a *type* is valid.
I check it and raise an *ArgumentException* if not valid.
I want to create a test for this behavior. I want to use *Assert.throws* or preferably *FSUnit* instead of a try/with block.

```
#package "FsUnit@3.4.1"
#package "nunit@3.11.0"

open System
open FSUnit

type configuration = {aaa:int}

type Client(conf:configuration) =
    do
        if conf.aaa < 3 then raise (ArgumentException("aaa must be at least 3"))

    member this.do_something() =
        ()
```

// TEST

```
    // 1. does not "compile"
    Assert.Throws<ArgumentException>(fun () -> Client(configuration) |> ignore)

    // 2. does not work
    //Assert.Throws<ArgumentException>( fun () ->
    //    let a = Client(configuration); 
    //    a
    //        |> ignore)

    // 3. does not work        
    (fun() -> Client(configuration)) |> ignore |> should throw typeof<ArgumentException>


    // 4. OK but... bleah!
    try
        Client(configuration) |> ignore
        Assert.Fail()
    with
        | :? ArgumentException -> Assert.Pass() |> ignore
        | _ -> Assert.Fail()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first approach works fine for me - I just had to define `configuration` which is not included in your question but, presumably, is defined somewhere in your actual file. The following compiles and behaves as expected for me:

```
let configuration = { aaa = 1 }
Assert.Throws<ArgumentException>(fun () -> Client(configuration) |> ignore)
```

Your second code snippet does not work because it has `ignore` in the wrong place - you are ignoring the entire function (which contains the code that you want to test) and then you are passing `unit` to the assertion. The `ignore` call needs to be *inside* of the function so that it ignores the result of calling the constructor. The following works for me:

```
(fun() -> Client(configuration) |> ignore) |> should throw typeof<ArgumentException>
```